# Double Javascript conditional expression in JSX issue. What is wrong?

Tags: jsx

I have a JSX element (Atlassian Cloud, Forge app) where editor and linter complain about the JSX syntax, but not if I do the same one level simpler.

The code is based on an array (`renderSource`). If empty, neither form nor table generated from the array should be rendered. But if the array is not empty, but the 'depth' to show is 0, the form should be shown so that the user can increase depth to show what is hidden otherwise.

This isn't correct:

```
    <Heading size="large">Design Library Info</Heading>
    {(renderSource.length > 0 ? 
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}><TextField label="Show depth" name="depth" type="number" defaultValue={formState.depth}/></Form>
      {(`${formState.depth}` !== "0" ?
      <Table>
        <Head><Cell><Text>This design depends on</Text></Cell><Cell><Text>Inherited requirements</Text></Cell></Head>
          {renderSource.map(depEntry => {
              return (
                <Row>
                  <Cell><Text><Link href={`${depEntry.link}`}>{depEntry.title}</Link></Text></Cell>
                  <Cell><Text>{depEntry.req}</Text></Cell>
                </Row>
              )
            })
          }
      </Table>:<Text>(Increase depth to show dependencies)</Text>)}
    :<Text>(This design does not have dependencies)</Text>)}
```

But this, with only one conditional, works: If depth is set to 0 in the form, the form is shown, but the table isn't:

```
    <Heading size="large">Design Library Info</Heading>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}><TextField label="Show depth" name="depth" type="number" defaultValue={formState.depth}/></Form>
      {(`${formState.depth}` !== "0" ?
      <Table>
        <Head><Cell><Text>This design depends on</Text></Cell><Cell><Text>Inherited requirements</Text></Cell></Head>
          {renderSource.map(depEntry => {
              return (
                <Row>
                  <Cell><Text><Link href={`${depEntry.link}`}>{depEntry.title}</Link></Text></Cell>
                  <Cell><Text>{depEntry.req}</Text></Cell>
                </Row>
              )
            })
          }
      </Table>:<Text>(Increase depth to show dependencies)</Text>)}
```

What is wrong with my syntax here?

Comment: "*where editor and linter complain about the JSX syntax*" and the error is?

Comment: The editor only gives soms colour clues (which seem to be wrong). The `forge` linter only says 'wrong' but gives no usable hint. The answer, by the way is, the inner  `<Form>` and  `<Table or Text>` combo needs to be embedded in a `<Fragment>` as well as JSX requires single objects at multiple levels.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `<Form> + <Table or Text>` combination requires to be surrounded by a `<Fragment>` element so it becomes a single 'element' (which JSX requires). Thanks to Atlassian staff for pointing this out to me.

The full example that works is

```
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Heading size="large">Design Library Info</Heading>
      {(maxRequirements.length > 0) ? 
        <Fragment>
          <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <TextField label="Show depth" name="depth" type="number" defaultValue={formState.depth}/>
          </Form>
          {(`${formState.depth}` !== "0" ?
            <Table>
              <Head><Cell><Text>This design depends on</Text></Cell><Cell><Text>Inherited requirements</Text></Cell></Head>
              {renderSource.map(depEntry => {
                return (
                  <Row>
                    <Cell><Text><Link href={`${depEntry.link}`}>{depEntry.title}</Link></Text></Cell><Cell><Text>{depEntry.req}</Text></Cell>
                  </Row>
                )
              })}
            </Table>:
            <Text>(Increase depth to show incoming dependencies and requirements. Edit page to add/delete dependencies)</Text>)
          }
        </Fragment>:
        <Text>(This design does not have incoming dependencies. Edit page to add.)</Text>
      }
    </Fragment>
  );
```

The inner `<Fragment>` surrounding was missing.

Note that the editor (Visual Studio Code with Babel Javascript extension cannot handle this perfectly at this stage, maybe because of the conditional.)